# How do I select 'N' range of distinct id's by evenly dividing their row counts?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to divide the output of the initial query below into 5 rows containing the MIN and MAX range of id's. The sum of the row count of the MIN and MAX range per row should be "almost" equal.

Initial query:

```
select id, count(id) as rcnt from table group by id order by id;

id     rcnt
----  |-----
1111  | 15
2222  | 35  
3333  | 25
5555  | 30
6666  | 20
7777  | 35  
8888  | 50
9999  | 50
```

Total: 260

Sum per row: ceil(260 / 5) = 52

Expected output:

```
min_id | max_id | sum (optional)
----   |--------|----
1111   | 2222   | 50
3333   | 5555   | 55
6666   | 7777   | 55
8888   | 8888   | 50
9999   | 9999   | 50
```

I did this by making my own algorithm using Perl by making use of the output of the initial query. **Would it be possible to get the same expected output using only a single query?**

If anyone is curious to why I'm doing this is because I am using SPOOL to dump the data using the range of these ID's into 5 files. Each file will be processed in parallel.

Any suggestion to optimize this process will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign each row to one of `N` buckets (in this case `5` buckets) in order of ascending `id`. Then for each `id` work out what is the mean bucket number its items are in and re-assign all the ids to that bucket (so there can be uneven numbers in each bucket). Then you can just find the minimum and maximum `id`s for each bucket:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0007e5/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id ) AS
  SELECT 1111 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 15 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 35 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3333 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5555 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6666 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7777 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 35 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8888 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9999 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MIN( id ) AS min_id,
       MAX( id ) AS max_id,
       SUM( cnt ) AS "sum"
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         COUNT(*) AS cnt,
         ROUND( AVG( grp ) ) AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           CEIL(
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id )
             / ( COUNT(*) OVER () + 1 )
             * 5                                 -- Number of buckets to assign rows to.
           ) AS grp
    FROM   table_name
    ORDER BY id
  )
  GROUP BY id
)
GROUP BY grp
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0007e5/11/0)**:

```
| MIN_ID | MAX_ID | sum |
|--------|--------|-----|
|   1111 |   2222 |  50 |
|   3333 |   5555 |  55 |
|   8888 |   8888 |  50 |
|   9999 |   9999 |  50 |
|   6666 |   7777 |  55 |
```

Comment: I just added **order by min_id** at the end. Overall this is excellent work! I changed the value of the bucket from 1-10 and works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I'm not so good with SQL so I did not know you could create tables that way. Thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 1):

One option uses `ROW_NUMBER`.  My approach is to assign a row number, beginning at 1, to each row of your current output, ordered by `id`.  Then, form groups using the formula `FLOOR((rn-1)/2)`.  This formula puts the first two rows together, then next together, and so on.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, COUNT(id) as rcnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id
)

SELECT
    MIN(id) AS min_id,
    MAX(id) AS max_id,
    SUM(rcnt) AS rcnt
FROM cte
GROUP BY FLOOR((rn-1) / 2)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried it out but I only got 4 rows in total.
3333-5555=55, 
6666-7777=55, 
8888-9999=100, 
1111-2222=50. Not what I was expecting.

Comment: @criz I just tested locally with your data and it works.  I suspect you have a problem with your data.

Comment: My table only has 2 fields. ID and SOME_VAL which has the value 1 by default. Total row count is 260. I will re-check.

Comment: Could you please help me check? I uploaded the screenshot of my query on some site and will expire in one day. [link](https://unsee.cc/2c88f6bb/)

Comment: Also, could you help me understand the formula **floor((rn-1) / 2)**?

Comment: I can't check my answer any more than I already have, my answer explains the logic behind that formula.  Test it out yourself to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to find out why using your query does not work on my end.

Comment: Correct me if my understanding is wrong but I checked that the **rn** value is 1-8. So the output of group by **floor((rn-1)/2)** is 0,1,2,3 thus creating only 4 rows. Also the ID starts from 1111 to 9999 but there is no ID = 4444. Can you please check?